# Draw square on each corner of an image in PHP

Tags: php

I want to draw square on each corner of my image, currently I have drawn one square at the top left of the image.

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
//rectangle coordinates
$array_rectangles = array(array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)),array('x1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y1' => mt_rand(0, 200),'x2' => mt_rand(0, 200),'y2' => mt_rand(0, 200)));
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 25, 153, 206);
//creating ten rectangles.
foreach ($array_rectangles as $key => $point) {
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, $point['x1'], $point['y1'], $point['x2'], $point['y2'], $white);
} 
//creating square
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 0, 0, 20, 20, $green);
imagepng($canvas,'img.png'); //saving image
```

[image]

I have tried `imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 200, 0, 20, 20, $green);` and i get the below results.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must try:

```
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 180, 0, 200, 20, $green);
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 0, 180, 20, 200, $green);
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 180, 180, 200, 200, $green);
```

x1 must be less than x2 or it will print backwards. Same for y1 and y2